# Trouble in working out that a strictly triangular $n \times n$ matrix is nilpotent of index $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if $A$ is a strictly triangular $n \times n$ matrix then $x^n = 0$ is the characteristics equation of $A$.Also if $A$ is non-zero then $A$ is not diagonalisable since $0$ is not a regular eigen value of $A$.So it's minimal polynomial is of degree at least $2$.If I can somehow show that the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$ cannot be less than $n$ then my purpose will be served. But I find difficulty to show this.Please help me in this regard.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered what form $A^2, A^3, ...$ take? Try out a few examples and see if you can notice a pattern.

Comment: But the minimal polynomial _divides_ the characteristic polynomial, so . . .

Comment: @quasi If minimal polynomial is of degree $n$ then it is surely $x^n$ and hence there does not exist any annihilating polynomial whose degree is less than $n$ and hence $n$ is the least positive integer such that $A^n = 0$.This will be sufficient to prove that the index of nilpotency of $A$ is $n$.Isn't it?

Comment: No need to worry about the degree of the minimal polynomial. After all, what polynomials are divisors of $x^n$?

Comment: Ok, I didn't read your title. You want index exactly n. But then you can't prove it (since it's false). For example the zero matrix. Most likely, you misread the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false.

For $n>1$, the zero matrix yields a trivial counterexample.

For a nonzero counterexample, let $n=3,\,$ and consider the matrix
$$
A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
It's easily verified that $A^2=0,\,$ hence $A$ has nilpotent index $2,$ not $3.$

Comment: Sorry it has been given by one of my friends to prove it and so I only tried to prove it instead of finding counter examples.I should justify it before doing such silly works.